# PostgreSQL 9.3: Alter database to set User

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to restore the `Database` in postgreSQL using the function.

In the function, I want to do the following steps:

1. First I want to alter the Database to the `SINGLE_USER` to access,
2. Restore the Database,
3. Again I want to alter the Database to set the `MLTI_USER`.

In SQL Server I used the following script:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM DISK = @Fullpath with replace;

ALTER DATABASE DBName SET MULTI_USER;
```

**Note**: `DBName` and `FullPath` will be the parameters to the function.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "single user mode" for a specific database in Postgres. And the process of restoring a backup depends on the format of the backup file. A SQL dump (aka "plain text dump") is restored by simply running the script. A custom format dump has to be restored using `pg_restore` - you can't do that through SQL statements. So how **exactly** did you take the backup?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, By using command prompt, using the script : `bin> pg_dump --Connection detials-- DBname > Location`.

Comment: That is a plain text dump. Just run `psql -f dump.sql`. Details are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE